# How can I select particular columns from postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Let's say I have following postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_summary(
  IN param INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    value NUMERIC,
    amount NUMERIC) AS $$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT sum(value) AS value, sum(amount) AS amount FROM ...

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I can select from this function like that:

```
SELECT * FROM get_summary(10);
```

But what if I want to select like that:

```
SELECT value, amount FROM get_summary(10);
```

But then I receive following error:

```
[2017-06-28 12:49:53] [42702] ERROR: column reference "value" is ambiguous
[2017-06-28 12:49:53] Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

How can I select particular columns from postgres function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use alias to table
for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_summary(
  IN param INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    value NUMERIC,
    amount NUMERIC) AS $$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT sum(t.value), sum(t.amount) AS amount FROM your_table t

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or try this:

```
SELECT t.value, t.amount FROM get_summary(10) t;
```